# Heuristic Value weird calculation

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

I'm currently working on A* algorithm small project but I think there is a problem with manhattan distance. I mean, when the code equals to:

```
inline int32 manhattanDistance(Node* startNode, Node* endNode)
{
    int32 deltaX = std::abs(startNode->position.x - endNode->position.x); 
    int32 deltaY = std::abs(startNode->position.y - endNode->position.y);

    return deltaX + deltaY;
}
```

It's returning the path as:
[Valid Manhattan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aicW.png)

but when I made a mistake before and the code was:

```
inline int32 manhattanDistance(Node* startNode, Node* endNode)
{
    int32 deltaX = std::abs(startNode->position.x - endNode->position.y); // there is a difference, startpos.x - endpos.y
    int32 deltaY = std::abs(startNode->position.y - endNode->position.y);

    return deltaX + deltaY;
}
```

and it's returning the path as:
[Invalid Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAI5c.png)

and the invalid's way looks better and more legit but slower, did I make any mistake or why the second one looks better?

And the diagonal distance works fine, so the problem is only in manhattan one.

Thanks for any answer

Comment: With invalid heuristic, it is hard to reason. and know if you really find the optimal path. As Start/end are not in the diagonal, your heuristic target another location near the target.

Comment: Your valid path seems strange, I would expect a `L`. Adding a tie-break to favorise diagonal seems harder with only integer precision.

Comment: You need to add explored colour or use different start & end, moving them away from the diagonal to see what goes wrong.

Comment: There are plenty of shortest paths between those points. If you want some kind of bias towards paths that "look better", you need to add that to the cost calculations. (You might also want to explore using a hexagonal grid.)

Comment: What's the cost function you're optimizing with the A* algorithm? Simply the path length? Then both solution paths you showed are equivalent. None is better or worse. If you personally like the alternating-directions version better, you have to express that somehow in the cost function, and change the heuristic function to match that.

Comment: I was going through wikipedia formula and pseudocode. I changed my int32 typedef to float and showing a bit "better" way, but I think they are just the same with the calculations, so I'm going to leave it at that i guess. Thanks for every answer!